# Why I get error "error no such user postgres", whe I use SQL code in PHP scripts?

Tags: php, postgresql

When I try to execute SQL code in my PHP scripts I get an error Error_no such_user (in browser)

- I have already tried to configure pg_hba.conf
- I have added the record with the trust value.

I have errors in postgresql log file (/var/lib/pgpro/std-11/data/log)

> ```
> 2019-01-21 17:00:56.516 MSK [1106] ERROR:  permission denied for table settings
> ```

Comment: I grant permission for databases, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please show some code that cause the issue?

Comment: I connect to the database via PDO It is just SQL insert                    2019-01-21 17:00:56.518 MSK [1106] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO settings ( name,type,hidden,value,misc ) VALUES ( 'option_video_size','2','0','VGA','{"QQVGA":"QQVGA","QVGA":"QVGA","VGA":"VGA","HD720":"HD720","HD1080":"HD1080"}' )
2019-01-21 17:00:56.518 MSK [1106] ERROR:  permission denied for table settings

Comment: You can either have the code use a different user or create the user in question.

Comment: How can I trace this?

Comment: it seem like you are not giving correct user details to database please check user and password in code and database

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have the required information about the system you have. Find out what user the webserver is started as.